# Getting the parent <tr> index value of a table using jquery in struts2-jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi i am trying to get the index of  using jquery in the below code:

```
<s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m"> 
            <tr>   <- this tr id i want
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" /></td> 
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" class="refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></a></td>     
            </s:if>
            </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </table>
```

and this is my jquery-ajx for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css" />
        <link href="css/common-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        <style>
        a{
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        var id;
         function refreshRecord(value)
        {
            id = value;
            alert(id);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.refresh').click(function(){
               var fileId=id;
               alert("ajax id is "+fileId);
               $.ajax({
               type:'post',
                url:'checkStatusAndNumRecs',
               data:{fileId:fileId},
                success:function(data)
               {
                    var obj=data.split(':');
                    var tr=$(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
                    alert("your tr is:"+tr);
               },
```

But issue is i am getting -1 as the index.please help me in this.any thing i am doing wrong,is the jquery-1.9.1.js valid can i use that to do this........
thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var tr=$(this).parent().parent().index();
```

Reason being that `$(this)` will give you img element. Its parent is the `<td>` element and its parent is the `<tr>` element which you are interested in. You added an extra parent() call

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

1. You are using `this` to refer the clicked element inside a ajax success handler, but inside the handler `this` doesn't refer the element. The solution is to use a closure variable
2. Use `.closet('tr')` to get the ancestor `tr` element

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.refresh').click(function () {
        var fileId = id;
        alert("ajax id is " + fileId);

        //a closure variable to hold the reference
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'checkStatusAndNumRecs',
            data: {
                fileId: fileId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = data.split(':');
                //use .closest() to get the tr
                var tr = $this.closest('tr').index();
                alert("your tr is:" + tr);
            },
```

Comment: that line is not executing